# Ordenar por mes en formato numérico c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema. Estoy intentado ordenar el response por mes numérico. Sin embargo, yo tengo que devolver el nombre del mes, y actualmente como lo estoy haciendo me está devolviendo el response ordenando los meses alfabeticamente. Que podría implementar para que se cumplan estas dos condiciones de "Ordenar por mes numérico" y "Devolver el nombre del mes".

```
TotalByMonths = result.GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    Month = x.Date.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES")),
                    ContractCode = x.ContractCode

            }).Select(g => new PaymentEvolutionDetailByMonth
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,
                AmountTotal = g.Sum(x => x.AmountTotal),
                Transactions = g.Sum(x => x.Transactions)

            }).OrderBy(g => g.Month).ToList(),
```

Espero su respuesta. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente pude corregirlo de la siguiente forma: quitando el OrderBy que se encontraba antes del .ToList() y agregandoló al comienzo de la sentencia. De esta forma:

```
TotalByMonths = result.OrderBy(g => g.Date.Month).GroupBy(x => new ....
```